# Finding a coordinate systems origin in another coordinate system

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

I am working with two 3d coordinate systems, A and B. Both coordinate systems have z facing upwards, but the x and y dimensions are rotated arbitrary amounts around z. I have a point, x,  that has a direction, t. I know the position of x, and the direction of t relative to both coordinate systems (t being the bearing relative to x in the z dimension). Using this information I need to find the origin of A in coordinate system B. How can i do this?

Comment: Do have the coordinates of the point relative to both systems?

Comment: Yes. My current approach is to find the offset from x to A's origin in reference frame B. And then add that to the position of x in B. But the numbers don't work depending on the relative position of everything.